# What's the meaning of "it()" in Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

I guess "it" is an abbreviation of a phrase. But I don't know what it is. Each time when I see this function I always try to find out its meaning.

Can somebody tell me about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`it('is really much more simple than you think)`

The `it()` syntax it is used to tell Jasmine what `it('should happen in your test')`

Answer (score 2):

Jasmine is a testing framework for behavior driven development. And **it** function's purpose is to test a behavior of your code.

It takes a string that explains expected behavior and a function that tests it.

```
it("should be 4 when I multiply 2 with 2", function() {
  expect(2 * 2).toBe(4);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an abbreviation, it's just the word `it`.

This allows for writing very expressive test cases in jasmine, and if you follow the scheme has very readable output.

Example:

```js
describe("My object", function () {
    it("can calculate 3+4", function () {
        expect(myObject.add(3, 4)).toBe(7);
    }
});
```

Then, if that test fails, the output will be like

```
Test failed: My object can calculate 3+4
Message: 
    Expected 6.99999 to equal 7
```

As you can see, this imaginary function suffers from some rounding error. But the point is that the resulting output is very readable and expressive, and the code is too.

The basic scheme in the code is: You `describe` the unit that will be tested, and then test `it`s various functions and states.

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine is a BDD testing framework (Behavior Driven Development) and differently from "stanndard" TDD (Test Driven Development) you are actually testing against behaviors of your application.
So "**it**" refers to the object/component/class/whatever your are testing rather than a method.
Imagine you are writing a test for a calendar widget in which you want to test that once a user click on the next arrow the widget changes the displayed month, you will write something like:

```
   it('should change displayed month once the button is clicked', function(){
     // assertions
   });
```

So, "**it**" is your calendar widget, you are practically saying "the calendar widget should change displayed month once the button is clicked".
In a TDD it would be instead something like:

```
testButtonArrowClickChangesDisplayedMonth()
```

In the end there isn't an actual difference, it's just a matter of style and readability.
Jasmine's tests are defined in a quite verbose manner, so developers can better understand what is the purpose of the test.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The name **it** is a pronoun for the test target, not an abbreviation of
> anything. It makes the spec [abbr. for specification] more readable by connecting the function
> name it and the argument description as a complete sentence.

https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#it